# google-material-icons aren't visible anymore

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, safari, google-material-icons

My Wordpress website uses google-material-icons that suddenly became not visible on browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox). Why? Can it have to do smth. with the Wordpress updates?

[On Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czvmS.png)

[On Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTDxu.png)

[On Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v07Q.png)

[Link to the website](https://sunnyshinyportugal.com/)

Example of css that exist in style style.css

```css
font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    content: "\E5CF";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 12px;
```

Comment: Fonts are visible on my all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It´s strange...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was **Cookie Notice & Compliance for GDPR / CCPA** plugin that was causing the problem / blocking the Material Icons to render. I disabled all plugins - the icons seemed working fine. And than I was enabling all plugins one by one.